HTTPD service needs to be restarted after system boot to work properly
On the server there is an Apache HTTP service that redirects the incoming https requests to some spring services (They only support http).
When the machine is restarted, the httpd service seems to be started correctly, but when a request is made (A post/get request to any of the spring services) the following error occurs:

"Error: write EPROTO 796680:error:100000f7:SSL
routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER: ..."

A simple restart of the httpd service fixes this problem.
This is quite annoying, because at every machine rest i need to restart the httpd service so that it works correctly
This is the .service file of httpd
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
Wants=httpd-init.service
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target httpd-init.service
Documentation=man:httpd.service(8)

[Service]
Type=notify
Environment=LANG=C

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful
# Send SIGWINCH for graceful stop
KillSignal=SIGWINCH
KillMode=mixed
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The system is Oracle Linux Server 8.9
What can the problem be?
